# Wordpress, MultiSite post de segundo site também aparecerem no site principal

Tags: php, wordpress

estou com uma dúvida no quesito multisites do wordpress... preciso que as postagens feitas no site2 sejam vistas também no site1, mas não o contrario...

existe essa possibilidade nativa?
existe algum plugin para fazer isto? ou alguma outra forma?

desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando [`switch_to_blog( $id )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) e [`restore_current_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/).

Dentro do tema do site1 você usa as funções pra buscar o conteúdo do site2. `switch_to_blog()` faz com que as consultas de banco sejam feitas relativas ao site que você especificar no parâmetro `$id`. Quando terminar de buscar as informações, use `restore_current_blog()` pra voltar ao banco do site 1.

Ex.:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(); // retorna os posts do site 1

switch_to_blog(2)
$posts = new WP_Query(); // retorna os posts do site 2
restore_current_blog();

$posts = new WP_Query(); // retorna os posts do site 1
```

Comment: onde exatamente adiciono este codigo

Comment: @Jefferson, essa é a pergunta do Milhão :) Adicione o código em qualquer template (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) ou no código de um Widget, ou em um Shortcode... as possibilidades são várias. Se não é programador, então são outros 500...